# secondary activity not starting on android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

**SOLVED: Just needed a full fresh install in my phone. I unistalled my app, then install it again via android studio and everything worked.**

I am trying to make an android app and I have an "about" menu item in my action bar. **When I click "About" Nothing happens, the new activity never stars.**

This is the code I have:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
    int id_view = viewGroup.getId();

    if (id == R.id.themeChanger) {
        if (id_view == R.id.activity_main) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_dark_modern);
        } else if(id_view == R.id.dark_modern) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_light_modern);
        } else if(id_view == R.id.light_modern)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    } else if(id == R.id.about)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayAbout.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Even though I checked that id is the same with R.id.about when I run the program and click the about on my options menu, the activity is not starting.

My DisplayAbout class is as simple as possible and it has only one text view:

```
package com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DisplayAbout extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_about);
}
```

Also in the manifest file I have this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayAbout"
        android:label="@string/about">
    </activity>
```

For example when id == R.id.themeChanger my code works like a charm, but not for the "about" below.

I work in android studio and I test on a real LG device.

**UPDATE: LOGCAT after the first clicked on options and after the second click on the about MenuItem**

```
06-28 18:12:30.410 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch Down

06-28 18:12:30.490 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP

06-28 18:12:30.510 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator W/dalvikvm: method Landroid/support/v7/widget/ListViewCompat;.lookForSelectablePosition incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/ListView;

06-28 18:12:30.520 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.PopupWindow.setEnterTransition, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.MenuPopupWindow.setEnterTransition

06-28 18:12:30.520 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16884: Landroid/widget/PopupWindow;.setEnterTransition (Landroid/transition/Transition;)V

06-28 18:12:30.520 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000a

06-28 18:12:30.520 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.PopupWindow.setExitTransition, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.MenuPopupWindow.setExitTransition

06-28 18:12:30.520 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16885: Landroid/widget/PopupWindow;.setExitTransition (Landroid/transition/Transition;)V

06-28 18:12:30.520 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000a

06-28 18:12:30.520 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator I/ListPopupWindow: Could not find method setEpicenterBounds(Rect) on PopupWindow. Oh well.

06-28 18:12:30.560 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.setPressedItem

06-28 18:12:30.570 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14365: Landroid/support/v7/widget/DropDownListView;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V

06-28 18:12:30.570 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000a

06-28 18:12:30.570 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.View.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.setPressedItem

06-28 18:12:30.570 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15927: Landroid/view/View;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V

06-28 18:12:30.570 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x004a

06-28 18:12:31.610 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch Down

06-28 18:12:31.630 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : Touch UP

06-28 18:12:47.240 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false

06-28 18:12:47.240 8991-8991/com.tzegian.simplelitecalculator D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
```

Comment: Do you have any errors or something i logcat?

Comment: Should I copy paste the logcat here at my first post? Cause it is really "big" and this is my first adnroid project so I do not know exactly about errors in logcat etc.

Comment: Paste just a fragment, what happend when you click option and a few next lines, filter that by you package name

Comment: That `Oh well` tho.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have verified ids being mentioned by you. and the

```
int id = item.getItemId();
```

are not null(Views I mean)

Try using,

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , DisplayAbout.class);
startActivity(i);

Comment: ID is not null I have checked it via debug. Also I used already that you said, it still did not work.

Comment: Then it might be a logical error..! Put another else block under your else if and debug you app.

Comment: I found a solution, I updated my initial post. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the id is wrong and the vm never enters into the if block. Try checking that.

Comment: I found a solution, I updated my initial post. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by unistalling the app from my phone, and then make a fresh full install again.